# Do unused indexes cause performance issues with sql server? And should I remove them?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've spent some time researching this and simply can't find a definitive answer. Here is the query I am using to look for indexes not used:

```
SELECT object_name(i.object_id) as tableName, i.name as indexName
FROM sys.indexes i
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s ON i.object_id = s.object_id AND i.index_id = s.index_id AND s.database_id = db_id()
WHERE objectproperty(i.object_id,'IsUserTable') = 1 and i.index_id> 0
AND s.object_id IS NULL
AND i.is_Primary_Key = 0
AND i.is_unique_constraint = 0
AND i.is_unique = 0
```

My understanding is that indexes returned by this query have not been utilized by the query optimizer since sql server was last restarted. I believe I should remove them....I just don't fully understand if there are performance implications or harm in leaving them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The harm of leaving them in is the space used and the increased work for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements as they have to keep the indexes updated as well as the base table.

Comment: @antlersoft: Yes, I've added that in.

Comment: I would just add that 'sometimes' dropping them can cause a performance impact, because even though they are not used, in some cases they could be providing statistics to the optimizer to choose a more effective execution plan. So just keep an eye out for that one.

Answer (score 5):

There are performance implications in leaving them there; indexes are maintained for every insert, update or delete to the table.

On the other hand, how do you know the index hasn't been used? The DMV is great, but it only covers the time since the last restart of SQL Server. So if the DMV does not have data for a full business cycle, you may be killing the CEO's annual report the next time he runs it.

In my humble opinion: Never, ever, ever drop an index based solely on the information in the usage DMV.

Comment: Also (and I deal with this a lot currently) those usage stats are reset on detach/reattach as well.  So if you deploy to production your stats are only as current as the age of your attached DB.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader(s) why this is the case. :-)

Comment: +1 - I was not planning on blindly removing these indexes, rather I was planning on using it as a baseline to review the indexes that "could" be removed.

Comment: No worries, it's just a VERY common knee-jerk reaction to eliminate them, whether it be from reviewing them manually or letting some 3rd party tool tell you it's ok. So I think it's important to clarify that there should be more research than just "yup, it's showing up as unused in the DMV..."